# Android Menu options in layout does not show icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I just added a Menu to my activity. Additionally I want to set some icons to each menu item. Therefore I tried both these methods but I do not see these icons on the device. What am I doing wrong ?

I tried the XML way:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@drawable/help"
    android:title="@string/menu_help" />
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/num"
    android:icon="@drawable/num_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_num" />
</menu>
```

Method 2:
In my code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        //Set icon for the menu button
        Drawable num_icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.num_icon);
        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(num_icon);
        Drawable settings_icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings);
        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(settings_icon);
        Drawable help_icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.help);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(help_icon);
        return true;
```

Also, could anyone tell me how big should these icon sizes be? Mine is256x256 pix.  Thanks

Comment: there is no icon in menu after android 4.x (well, if menu button is on ActionBar then, yes, it can have icon but not in menu overlay("three dots" button or hard menu button)

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750635/icon-in-menu-not-showing-in-android>?  check this you will get solution for your question

Answer (score 1):

In the android sdk menu icons are of the following sizes:

> ```
> ldpi 32 x 32 px
> mdpi: 36 x 36 px
> hdpi: 48 x 48 px
> xhdpi: 64 x 64 px
> ```

256x256 is too large.

Answer (score 1):

use following code it may help you..
menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item 
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
          android:title="Bookmark" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
          android:title="Save" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
          android:title="Search" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
          android:title="Share" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
          android:title="Delete" />  

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
          android:title="Preferences" /> 
</menu>
```

Now open your main Activity class file and put following code
MenusActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_preferences:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have need to small changes in your manifest file according to your need you can change theme I get the solution for above problem with small change i.e.even using any version of android it will work for (2.3 to latest version 4.4 kitkat also).

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
```