# icon in menu not showing in android

Tags: android

I want to add menu handler to my project. I read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html too, its very simple but the icon is not shown. I am very confused. I even added a menu item programmatically.

My code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Quit").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item 
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item 
    -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark" 
          android:icon="@drawable/update"
          android:title="@string/Update" />

</menu>
```

Comment: which android version your device running?

Comment: 4.1.2 , but i run http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/ and its worked fine

Comment: this is definitely one of the most frustrating problems with Android. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Their documentation does exactly what you're doing, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: hello in androidhive demo it showed lower version than 3.0 if you run your program in 3.0 lower version  2.2,2.3 etc it will work

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html says that icons are not supported or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To show icons in Overflow menu in ActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design. This is a design decision by Google.

You can read more about it in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) on Android developers blog.

Comment: but i run http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/ and its worked,

Comment: Does your activity extends `ActionBarActivity` when it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the target API in both version? The same? Are you building against the same API level?

Comment: no you right, my api version is 4.1 and my sample that i have worked with lower version of 3

Comment: The default is to not show them, but nowadays you can show them. See Pranob's answer.

Comment: @Szymon: Thanks for providing the link to the Android Developers Blog. That's a short & succinct blog that covers a lot in a few lines. Very resourceful. And yes, Pranob's answer has a drawback. Although you can show the icons of the overflow items, the icon color doesn't change according to the day/night theme of the device, thereby rendering the icons invisible either in day theme or in night. Following the Google's design standards as mentioned in the blog is the optimal option in my opinion.

Answer (score 48):

After Long try i found below solution which might help others to save there time. Basically, the solution provided by "lbarbosa", i like to thanks to him sincerely.

Tried this based on the previous answers and it works fine, at least with more recent versions of the support library (25.1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){
        MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
        m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The only real working solution, but you need to add `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")`

Comment: Seriously guys, THE ONLY REAL WORKING SOLUTION. and yeah dont forget to put @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") over the method public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: Excellent! Bro, you really save my time.

Comment: Nowadays, and at least for Android kotlin, the method name appears to be setForceShowIcon().

Comment: There's a drawback to Pranob's answer that I encountered a few days ago. With the given code, although you can show the icons of the overflow items, the icon color doesn't change according to the day/night theme of the device, thereby rendering the icons invisible either in day theme or in night.

Answer (score 28):

No matter what design choices where made by the system, you can circumvent this with the solution provided in [the top upvoted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

Code below for completeness. Tested working on `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)
{
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "onMenuOpened", e);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

Comment: This ALMOST worked for me.  For reasons I do not understand, the featureId value was 0 for me.  I replaced the first if statement with
    "if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL && menu != null){"
and it worked.  Although, I am not sure that "FEATURE_OPTION_PANEL" is the correct meaning of the 0 my app is getting.

Comment: Well, most Java workarounds for Android's infamous embedded "best-practices" (a.k.a. pull an Apple on the developer API) rely on either Java reflection or outright source copypasta to project (which is by far less appealing, yet safer). Case in point, using the former people feel the need to over-condition the change. In this case, it was arbitrated that the adjustments were specific to for ActionBar calls, but there might be other valid such as yours, depending on API level and whatnot

Comment: Since my featureId is 108 not 8, can I replace the `featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` -> `(featureId & Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`

Comment: don't really get the single ampersand (&) usage there, but as I said before anyways, you can attempt this onMenuOpened override on any activity, even without the first if() that checks if the feature exists (you can still check for menu != null of course), and see if behavior is desirable across devices/SDKs in your case.+

Comment: Thank you! I used your code, but replaced featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR with (featureId & Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR. @leRobot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757447/understanding-the-behavior-of-a-single-ampersand-operator-on-integers explains how and why the ampersand works and once you read that, you'll agree that the usage here is very smart :)

Comment: ah thx. Kinda low level notation for Java IMHO, but yeah, logic seems sound

Comment: Great, it works, just have a question, if I just check if(menu != null), what will the problem?

Comment: I believe you might get unexpected behavior for other scenarios where onMenuOpen gets triggered but you don't have an action bar. For example, you might get the NoSuchMethodException. Basically, if your activity has an action bar there should be no problem, but check here for reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html

Answer (score 19):

Old question but hope it will help someone.

use the following code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="Share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share" /></menu>
```

note i used `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`

Comment: This is I needed to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can add to your XML file the attribute `android:showAsAction="always"` inside your item element. It then will show the relevant menu option as an icon inside your action bar.

Note that it will be *instead* of the text in the menu.

For further read, look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) under *android:showAsAction*.

Answer (score 4):

```
/* menu code */   
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/one" android:title="one"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item android:id="@+id/two" android:title="two"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item android:id="@+id/three" android:title="three"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"  />
    </menu>
   /* Java code */

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu,menu);
            if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){
                MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
                m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget all those, do this step.
add `app:showsAsAction="always"` to your item. If you use      `android:showsAsAction="always"` you won't get the solution.
Try with adding app attribute to your item.

Comment: This simply makes it appear on the actual bar (not in the menu) as an action item.

Answer (score 1):

I put explicit icons in onCreateOptionsMenu method using below code

for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);

```
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.print) {
            item.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.print));
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Working with `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, is making the input for the icons a very difficult task. You need to implement `onMenuOpen`, super method from `AppComactActivity` class. After this check, if the menu is not null. If the menu is not null pass Method class like this and `setOptionalIconsVisible` to true with boolean.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {

    if(menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e("MAIN", "onMenuOpened", e);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attr inside item tag in your menu.xml

```
app:showAsAction="always
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  menu.add(0, 0, 0, "androidDemo").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

and in xml:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/menuUpdate"
  android:icon="@drawable/update_icon"
  android:title="@string/Update" 
  android:showAsAction="always"/>
```