# Custom rows for menu items in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create kind of list view with custom rows in menu in action bar. something like this:

[image]

I have searched a lot on web but could not find anything useful. How can I achieve this thing? I know you can bind custom views with items in menu but how?
I want to bind list view with this item:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: looks like a navigation drawer on the right

Comment: no, its not navigation drawer. this is menu in action bar

Comment: Did u find any workaround for this?

Comment: @John yes, check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861196/showing-custom-layout-on-overflow-drop-down-menu-item-android/23468740#23468740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had figured out after a while. If you want to list items with just icon and title in over flow menu, you need to do nesting of items within items or group them using `menu` tag.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/add_source"
                android:icon="@drawable/add_on"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/add_source"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/channel_setup"
                android:icon="@drawable/channelsetup_on"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/channel_setup"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/time_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/weather"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cloud"
        android:orderInCategory="98"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/weather_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="97"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        android:title="@string/search_title"/>    
</menu>
```