# PopupMenu not displaying images

Tags: android, xml, menu, popup, popupmenu

I have seen the answer from the guy Shahzeb in the topic
[Showing Custom Layout on Overflow Drop Down Menu Item? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861196/showing-custom-layout-on-overflow-drop-down-menu-item-android)

My xml looks like

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_grid"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Grid"
    android:icon="@drawable/grid_button"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_list"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="List"
    android:icon="@drawable/list_button"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_history"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="History"
    android:icon="@drawable/history_button"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Favourite"
    android:icon="@drawable/favorite_button"/>
```

But the result i am getting is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOmcg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which resolution are the drawables you are using? Try to use something like 32x32 or 48x48. I guess it might solve your problem