# How to show both icon and text in multiple menu items in action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

Attached is the screenshot which shows the menu items.[image]

Comment: AFAIK, the native overflow menu does not support icons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861196/showing-custom-layout-on-overflow-drop-down-menu-item-android)

Comment: Use Custom menu to show icon and text

Comment: @Aks4125 You r right. Its working. and  sarika I tried custom, it wont work

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for an Answer, here's how I got it -

***menu.xml***

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <item 
        android:id="@+id/a_More"
        android:icon="@drawable/more"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="More" >

        <menu>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/MENU_GOTO"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" 
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/go_to"
        android:title="Go To Page"/>

        <item
        android:id="@+id/MENU_OUTLINE"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" 
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline"
        android:title="Table of Contents"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/MENU_OPTIONS"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" 
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/MENU_EXIT"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" 
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
        android:title="Exit"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

***And in Activity -***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
return super .onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Here the important xml attributes should be known are

android:icon – Defines the icon of the action item.
android:title – Title for the icon.
android:showAsAction – Defines the visibility of the action item. It accepts following values.
**always: Forces to display the icon always irrespective of space available. This way is not suggested**.
withText Displays a text along with the icon. Normally the text value defined by android:title will be displayed

You can use withText for android:showAsAction as below for each of the items which you want to display in action menu.
android:showAsAction="withText"

Answer (score 0):

```
     actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide the action bar title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Enabling Spinner dropdown navigation
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Spinner title navigation data
    navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Local", R.drawable.ic_location));
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("My Places", R.drawable.ic_my_places));
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Checkins", R.drawable.ic_checkin));
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Latitude", R.drawable.ic_latitude));     

    // title drop down adapter
    adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);

    // assigning the spinner navigation     
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```