# How to set only image as menu item in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-optionsmenu

I have created options menu it has some attributes like `android:I'd, android : title,android:icon` etc how can I set a image as android option menu and also I want title of the item below the icon not beside the icon

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861196/showing-custom-layout-on-overflow-drop-down-menu-item-android) and [this](http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html) as a start. Build a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this easily and you should not. What you explain sounds more like [Tabs](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html) to me, which you could use instead. With these you'll get text below the icon out of the box.

Comment: These are not tabs am talking about menu items