# android overflow menu item is unable to display both icon and title

Tags: android

I am trying to set image in overflow menu items like as in flipkart.But I am unable to set image.Can anybody provide me code snippet for doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add icons in overflow menu item as per googles new change, If u still want, try this.
for device with overflow hardware button:
override hardware button click and show a transparent fragment with list view as like over flow menu in samsung devices(S3, s4) with icon.

for devices without hardware button:
use sub menu to look as menu. google still supports icon in sub menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying on Android 3.0+, it won't show icons in the menu items. Google has removed them in order to make the menu look similar on different apps. See [icon in menu not showing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750635/icon-in-menu-not-showing-in-android) and on [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's supposed to work.

If the icon shows in the action bar, it will only show the icon (with an optional title by using `android:showAsAction="always|withText"` or `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`).

If the icon does not show in the action bar, it will only show in the overflow menu as text. Note that there is no `"withIcon"` enum value for the `android:showAsAction` attribute.