# Change drawable color in menu

Tags: android, xml, menu, popup

I have created a `popup menu` and inside the popup.xml, I have two icons. I trying to change the color of icon inside the popup.xml but the color always remains white (original color).

> Is there a way to change the drawable color in menu ?

**popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt1"
        android:icon="@drawable/change_pic"
        android:color="@color/green"
        android:title="Change Picture" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt2"
        android:icon="@drawable/change_pin"
        android:title="Change Password" />
</menu>
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**Code**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_task, menu); // for the two icons in action bar
        return true;
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.menu:
                    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu);
                    MenuBuilder menuBuilder =new MenuBuilder(this);
                    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup, menuBuilder);
                    MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(this, menuBuilder, menuItemView);
                    optionsMenu.setForceShowIcon(true);
                    optionsMenu.show();

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the image is actually white color.

Comment: Get the drawable from icon menu and apply color filter in that

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of your icon - 'change_pic', which is present in drawable folder ?

Comment: Can u show an screenshot how ur getting nw

Comment: and how u need it

Comment: @Swas_99 check my post

Comment: @Athul check my post

Comment: U will have to add an icon with the color u needto change color

Comment: @Athul I have added `android:color="@color/green`

Comment: @MD Sir check my post again

Comment: you must using drawable image for changing font and color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750635/icon-in-menu-not-showing-in-android

Comment: U will have add the respective image with respective image manually for changing the icon color

Comment: @shayanpourvatan my image is showing, but white color

Comment: @FarzadSarseifi I saved them in drawable

Comment: did you inflate popup as menu ? ( in onCreateOption or onPrepare )

Comment: It showing like that because the image u saved in drawable in white

Comment: Change the icon color in drawable

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes.

Comment: so see accepted answer in my link : ( If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design. This is a design decision by Google. )

Comment: @shayanpourvatan my mistake...I didn't inflate popup as menu in onCreateOption. I have inflated another menu.

Comment: so how to show popup.xml file ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu:
                View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu);
                MenuBuilder menuBuilder =new MenuBuilder(this);
                MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup, menuBuilder);
 Drawable yourdrawable1 = menuBuilder.getItem(0).getIcon(); // change 0 with 1,2 ... 
            Drawable yourdrawable2 = menuBuilder.getItem(1).getIcon();
            yourdrawable1.mutate();
            yourdrawable2.mutate();
             yourdrawable1.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
yourdrawable2.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(this, menuBuilder, menuItemView);
                optionsMenu.setForceShowIcon(true);
                optionsMenu.show();

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will change the color of change pic image

Comment: Please try and let me knw

Comment: If I use your code, my action bar icon will gone, because I add them in  `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_task, menu);`

Comment: Updated it ...Tried this way?

Comment: Thanks,it works. But if I want to change the second items to green, what is the best approach ?

Comment: change the get Item number

Comment: I need to create another Drawable object ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130577/discussion-between-athul-and-john-joe).

Comment: @JohnJoe Did u try?

Answer (score 1):

change_pic is image file or vector asset file ???
If it is vector asset then you can change the color from .xml file and if you are using image file then i suggest you to use vector asset file.

Comment: I download from https://material.io/icons/#ic_power_settings_new. Is it consider vector asset file ?

Comment: save it in .svg format and then you can convert it in vector asset.for converting .svg to vector asset go to drawable>>new>>vector asset>>select local file(svg,psd) and then select your .svg file path.

Comment: It will generate one .xml file.In .xml file you can change the color from android:fillColor="#000000". put your color code.